# How to calculate sample size for blocked-design two-way ANOVA?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, statistical-power, two-way

Does anyone know of a good online calculator or at least a good paper that details how to calculate the needed sample size for a blocked-design two-way ANOVA experiment?  I've seen a ton of references showing how to *analyze* the data from such an experiment, but none about how to properly *design*  it and estimate the required sample size.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As for a good reference, I would suggest Ryan, T.P., *Sample Size Determination and Power*, Wiley, 2013. It covers pretty much everything regarding the comparison of means and proportions, regression settings, and a large amount experimental designs.<sup>1</sup> Randomized Complete Block Designs are treated in $6.2.5.

Power analysis in this case generally relies on the noncentrality parameter, which varies from one design to the other. Usually, you have to specify $\sigma^2$ (variance of the individual observations under the null hypothesis) and theoretical means for each block. The [Java applets for power and sample size](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/%7Erlenth/Power/) has some utilities to work with this kind of design (via the "Balanced ANOVA" menu dialog).

[image]

**Sidenote:** Blocking reduces the degrees of freedom for the error term, which reduces power, yet a randomized complete block design (RCBD) is generally more powerful than a completely randomized design.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Giesbrecht & Gumpertz, *Planning, Construction, and Statistical Analysis of Comparative Experiments*, (Wiley, 2004), is cited by this author but I haven't read this book, so I can't say anything.</sub>