# G*Power settings to find minimum sample size for a 2x2x3 design

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, sample-size, statistical-power, gpower

For a power analysis, does "number of measurements" refer to the number of LEVELS or the total number of CONDITIONS?

I have a three-way (2x3x2) ANOVA that is entirely within-subjects, and I'm running a power analysis for minimum sample size. In total, there are 12 different conditions that participants have to complete (2x2x3). So, should "number of measurements" be 12? OR does number of measurements just refer to the amount of levels (which would be 2+2+3 = 7)?

I've been told that G*Power isn't equipped to handle three-way designs, but I found PASS to be overly complicated, and MOREpower gave me a minimum sample size that seemed way too small.

Comment: As a sidenote, you might be interested in those [Java applets for power and sample size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/496375/930) for within-subject designs.